# ng-class with dnyamic values and expression

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have following ng-class syntax with profileView.rating is value from API.

```
<span   ng-class="{'badge-rating-{{profileView.rating}}*2':true}"></span>
```

I have to apply class for this span like badge-rating-1,badge-rating-5.Now If I have profileView.rating value 0.5 then for this span  'badge-rating-0.5*2'
How Can I solve this expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this in your ng-class syntax

```
ng-class="{'badge-rating-{{(profileView.rating*2)}}':true}"
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<span   ng-class="'badge-rating-{{profileView.rating*2}}'"></span>
```